# conditionally hiding & unhiding image folders in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-gallery, mediastore

The following is my requirement:
I have a checkbox in my activity. If the checkbox is checked, I will add a '.nomedia' file to hide all the photos in my folder. If the checkbox is unchecked, I will delete the '.nomedia' file, to display all the photos in the folder. My problem is, though the creation/deletion of '.nomedia' file is successful, the hiding/unhiding of the images are not happening in the android gallery app. How can I force the gallery app to show/hide the folder contents according to my checkbox state?

The following is my code:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                                hideFolder();                                    
                            } else {
                                unHideFolder();                                    
                            }

    private void hideFolder() {
        File targetDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + CONSTANTS.MYFOLDERPATH);
        File noMediaFile = new File(targetDir, ".nomedia");
        try {
            if (!noMediaFile.exists()) {
                noMediaFile.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void unHideFolder() {
        File targetDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + CONSTANTS.MYFOLDERPATH);
        File noMediaFile = new File(targetDir, ".nomedia");
        if (noMediaFile.exists()) {
            noMediaFile.delete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to force start media scan. Thus to index of media on the sdcard, .nomedia will no reflect immediately. On way to do that is to clear the data of Gallery app.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How to do a force scan? @Zingking